# Connection time-out on telegram-bot

Tags: python, webhooks, telegram-bot, cherrypy

I am using python and cherrypy with my telegram bot.

Also, I am using webhooks instead of long polling.
But the bot doesn't work. `Get_webhook_info` returns this message:

```
{ "ok": true,  
  "result": 
  { "url": "https://IP/571605115:token/",
    "has_custom_certificate":true,
    "pending_update_count":3,
    "last_error_date":1524150207,
    "last_error_message":"Connection timed out",
    "max_connections":40
  }
}
```

Could somebody please help with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: It's also telling you explicitly what the problem is... `Connection timed out` when accessing URL `https://ip/571605115:token/`. Try emulating the request yourself (eg using Postman. Alternatively, Chrome Dev tools can give you a curl command to run [right-click on the request in the network tab]).

Comment: How about post data to yourself?

Comment: So I just have to put the URL with getwebhookinfo to Postman?

Comment: I have the same problem. Testing the hook with Postman, everything is OK, but I cannot make it works with Telegram bot.

My hook is hosted at hook.io

I'm struggling with this error since days. Could be due to ssl certificate?